# get members of a DL

Tags: exchange-server, powershell-3.0

my question seems to be basic, but so far i have spent several hours already trying to figure it out. Basically the goal is to search for the transport rule that block members of a DL (Distribution List) from sending external email. then display the members of that DL too.

What the below code does is that it can display the Transport rule and the DL value in "FromMemberOf" but it doesn't display the members of it. If for example I ran just $dl_info.FromMemberOf it does show the DL groups so Im sure that is being picked up (see attached screenshots) thus I tried to use it as my array when I use the foreach-objct . ALso I noticed that its being called RawIdentity which i didnt define. ANy thoughts?

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$sid = "SID",
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$ExchGuid = "ruleid"
)

$dl_info = @()
foreach ($rule in $ExchGuid){

    $dl_info += Get-TransportRule | where {$_.guid -eq $rule} | select Priority, name, RejectMessageEnhancedStatusCode, ExceptIfFromMemberOf, FromMemberOf, @{n="DL_Block_Members";e={$dl_info.FromMemberof | ForEach-Object (Get-DistributionGroupMember $_ -ResultSize unlimited | select name)}}
}

$dl_info
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by using Pscustomobject. It could display the DL member but I have to work on the script to be able to search the account membership. THats for another day

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$sid = "sid",
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$ExchGuid = "ruleid"
)


$TRule_Info = @()
$DL_Info = @()

foreach ($rule in $ExchGuid){
    $TRule_Info = Get-TransportRule | where guid -EQ $rule
        foreach ($group in $TRule_Info){
            $ht = [pscustomobject]@{
            SID = $sid
            RuleName  = $TRule_Info.Name
            DL_Group_Exemption = $TRule_Info.ExceptIfFromMemberOf
            DL_BlockGroup_Members = $TRule_Info.FromMemberOf
            }
$DL_Info += $ht
        }
}

$DL_Info
```